# Using Maven 3, how do I overwrite a file defined in one of the dependencies?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I have a multi-module Java EE application including a module for the web archive.
The WAR declares a dependecy on another WAR which provides a general purpose CSS.
I'd like to overwrite the provided CSS in my local WAR to add some specific behaviour.
So I copied the CSS from the dependency and placed it in the very same directory in my local WAR (being src/main/webapp/css/file.css).

I assumed Maven to merge these files, so my changes eventually become visible.
However, after deploying the application I still end up with the general purpose version provided by the dependency.

Is there any solution / plugin to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need is Maven's overlay feature which can merge 2 war projects:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html